# Woocommerce price range hyphen color change

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce

As you can see in the picture I have attached, I can't change the color of the hyphen from price range in a Woocommerce store. I was able to change the color of prices, but the color of the hyphen does not change with that.
I'll add my previous CSS below.

Does anyone have a hint? Thanks in advance.

```
.product .summary .price del .amount {
color: #000000;
text-decoration: line-through
}

.price ins .woocommerce-Price-amount {
color: #000000 !important;
}

.price .woocommerce-Price-amount {
color: #000000 !important;
}

.woocommerce-variation-price ins:before {
color: #000000!important;
}
```

[image: I mean the red hyphen and not the price as such.]

Answer (score 0):

In my woocommerce shop, on the product page I have this markup:

```
<p class="price" style="">
<span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">
<bdi><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">DKK</span>&nbsp;50,00</bdi></span> 
    – 
<span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><bdi>
<span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">DKK</span>&nbsp;90,00</bdi></span> 
<small class="woocommerce-price-suffix">inkl. moms</small></p>
```

So in this case, the following worked for me to color only the hyphen:

```
.price {
    color: #000 !important;
}
```

If that doesn't work for you, could you try showing your HTML markup?